# Pyzmq Error in IPython Notebook

Tags: python, ipython, pyzmq

I'm trying to run IPython notebook in Vista. I believe I installed all the necessary  dependencies (listed [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/install/install.html#dependencies-for-the-ipython-html-notebook)) with easy_install. IPython runs fine. But when I try and run the IPython notebook everything starts up fine but then the kernel dies once I try to do anything. I get the following  confusing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.11-py2.7.egg\IPython\zmq\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    minimum_pyzmq_version, pyzmq_version))
ImportError: IPython.zmq requires pyzmq >= 2.1.4, but you have 2.1.11
```

2.1.11 >= 2.1.4 so I'm not sure what the problem is. 2.1.11 is the latest version of pyzmq ([here](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq) is the project page).

[Update: Thanks @ThomasK. I was already running IPython 0.12 but I ran easy_install --upgrade on both IPython and pyzmg and that fixed it.]

Comment: Your traceback says `ipython-0.11-py2.7.egg`, so there must have been an IPython 0.11 installation getting involved somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bug has been fixed in IPython 0.12, so you'll need to upgrade. You need 0.12 to run the notebook, anyway.

If you're having trouble upgrading, try deleting the folder where IPython 0.11 is installed, and then installing again with easy_install.